# Неявное преобразование void* в указатель на объект

Tags: c++

Почему в первом случае работает а во втором нет, ведь в обоих случаях справа от оператора присваивания тип void*

```
class A {

public:
    void *operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void *p);
};

void *A::operator new(size_t size) {
    printf("Allocated %d bytes\n", size);
    return malloc(size);
}

void A::operator delete(void *p) {
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    A* p = new A(); // 1 Почему тут работает

    void* v = p;
    A* p1 = v;      // 2 А тут нет

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы, очевидно, путаете *new-expression*

```
new A()
```

и перегруженную функцию `operator new`

```
void *A::operator new(size_t size)
```

Это совершенно разные, отдельные сущности, хоть и связанные между собой. Ваш `operator new` - это функция выделения "сырой" памяти, вызываемая изнутри реализации *new-expression*. Перегружая `operator new` вы не перегружаете всё *new-expression*, а перегружаете лишь его маленький внутренний кусочек.

Примерный алгоритм работы *new-expression* выглядит так:

1. Вычислить требуемый размер памяти.
2. Выделить "сырую" память вызовом функции `operator new` (или `operator new[]` для массивной версии `new []`).
3. Если память выделена успешно, сконструировать в ней объект(-ы) вызовом конструктора(-ов), если эти конструкторы существуют и не *тривиальны*.
4. Если конструктор выбросил исключение, освободить "сырую" память вызовом соответствующей функции `operator delete` (для массивной версии: предварительно деструктировать уже успешно сконструированные элементы, если деструкторы существуют и не *тривиальны*).
5. В противном случае, вернуть указатель на сконструированный объект (или на начало массива).

Ваш `operator new` используется только на шаге 2. На остальную функциональность *new-expression* ваш перегруженный `operator new` никак не влияет. *New-expression* `new A`, по определению, возвращает наружу `A *` и всегда будет возвращать наружу именно `A *`.

Обратите, кстати, внимание, что в случае массивной версии `new []` указатель, возвращенный из *new-expression*, может не совпадать по значению с указателем, возвращенным из функции выделения "сырой" памяти `operator new[]`.

Comment: да я так и понял, но твой ответ все устаканил. спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Выражение `new A();` возвращает `A *` (в отличие от функции `A::operator new`), аналогичный код будет:

```
A * p;
{
   void * const pv{A::operator new(sizeof(A))};
   try
   {
       new (pv) A();
   }       
   catch(…)
   {
       A::operator delete(pv);
       throw;
   }
   p = static_cast<A *>(pv);
}
```

Если же вызвать функцию `A::operator new` напрямую, то будет такая же ошибка, как и во втором случае:

```
A* pv = A::operator new(sizeof(A)); // error
```

Comment: так new же перегружен и у перегруженного new возвращаемый тип void*

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Это фишка языка такая. Если его вызвать вот так: `A *p = operator new(sizeof(A));`, тогда действительно вернет `void *`. А `new A();` сам приводит указатель к нужному типу.

Comment: значит new вызывает operator new?  а после того как operator new вернет значение, new преобразует его в нужный тип?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov Выражение `new` помимо вызова функции выделения памяти `new` еще осуществляет вызов конструктора, обработку исключений и преобразование результата.